# Puppet: Virtual resources and mysql_grant

Tags: puppet

I have a problem with virtual resources and the mysql_grant resource. I have following code:

```
@mysql_grant { "foo@%/*.*":
   user => "$user",
   name => "$user/*.*",
   table => '*.*',
   privileges => ['ALL'],
   options => ['GRANT'],
   tag => 'admin',
}
Mysql_grant <| tag == 'admin' |> { user => "bar@%",}
```

The user variable gets interpolated correct, but the name one not:

```
Error: Validation of Mysql_grant[foo@%/*.*] failed: name must match user and table parameters: $name = /*.* / $user = bar@% at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-0ad5afab2ae36c0b761cc49e6f9f9bf9/development.db_slave.pp:103
```

I added some debug output, the $name :"/*.*" one lacks of the $user part, but as you can see the $user variable ist  set correct: $user = "bar@%".

Do you have any suggestions what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

> The user variable gets interpolated correct, but the name one not

I don't see any evidence to support that claim, but I do see some evidence of some misunderstanding on your part.  Specifically, you say:

> I added some debug output, the $name :"/*.*" one lacks of the $user part, but as you can see the $user variable ist set correct: $user = "bar@%".

... but the code you present neither defines nor uses any variable named `$user`, and though it *uses* a variable `$name`, it does not *define* that variable.  Supposing that `Mysql_grant` is a defined type, such variables exist within the body of its definition, but that's an altogether separate scope.  I guess you're trying to encode a rule that the resource's `name` attribute should have a value derived from that of its `user` attribute, but it just doesn't work that way.

Here are some of the key things to understand:

- Resource declarations, including of virtual and exported resources, do not establish new variable scopes, nor are any variables defined within a resource declaration that are not identically defined immediately outside that definition.
- Resource declarations, including of virtual and exported resources, are fully evaluated in the scope where they appear, not the scope where the declared resource is realized / imported (if that differs).

Thus, given a declaration such as yours:

```
@mysql_grant { "foo@%/*.*":
   user => "$user",
   name => "$user/*.*",
   # ...
}
```

You are declaring resource `Mysql_grant['foo@%/*.*']` as a virtual resource with `user` and `name` attributes derived from the value of variable `$user` in the surrounding scope.  The error message you presented suggests that `$name` is in fact not defined or is defined with an empty value in that scope, which is entirely plausible.

You then realize that resource via a collector with a property override:

> ```
> Mysql_grant <| tag == 'admin' |> { user => "bar@%",}
> ```

you have thereby overridden the declared value of attribute "user", but not overridden the declared value of attribute "name".  If these are required to correspond to each other then that seems unlikely to work, unless by sheer luck.

If you can, it would be better to declare the wanted `user` and `name` properties in the first place.  If you must perform overrides with a collector, then every property you want to override must be overridden separately.  For example,

```
Mysql_grant <| tag == 'admin' |> {
  user => "bar@%",
  name => "bar@%/*.*",
}
```